# Secure WebSocket SSL certificate installation in Cocos Creator 3.8+

Tags: wss, cocoscreator

Prior to Cocos Creator 3.5, you are able to add SSL certificates when creating websocket clients. We are using Cocos Creator 3.8 and we want our game to carry the certificates in case the certificate authority is not available in certain regions. How can this be achieved?